# URL Masking with DNS and/or Mod_Rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, dns

I want to setup a system so that multiple custom domains like [mydomain.com/params] will redirect to [myapp.com/mydomain.com/params].  Can I do this using **only DNS settings**?

I'm guessing that is not possible, so would it be a better solution to direct mydomain1.com, mydomain2.com, mydomain3.com, etc. to one IP address then use Mod_Rewrite to direct each request (invisibly) to myapp.com/mydomain#.com/params ?  Each redirected URL leads to content that is loaded from a centrally hosted CMS.

Any suggestions, resources, and/or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the solution:

1. Set DNS Address records for all vanity domains to the same IP address (so d1.com, d2.com, d3.com, etc. all have DNS A records set to one IP or FQDN for example)
2. Setup the server with one VirtualHost using the IP as the domain
3. Within that VirtualHost's root directory, create a .htaccess that sets up the mod_rewrite
4. Use the following for the mod_rewrite in the .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://myapp.com/%1/$1 [P,R=301,L]
```

%1 = the domain that is requested, so www.d1.com or d1.com

$1 = the rest of the URL that comes after the vanity URL (d1.com/**everyting/else**

This config invisibly redirects all requests.

Examples:

```
d1.com => returns content from => myapp.com/d1.com/

www.d1.com => returns content from => myapp.com/www.d1.com/

d1.com/blog/post/1 => returns content from => myapp.com/d1.com/post/1
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use only DNS for that.

If every domain can run standalone (www.domain.com) this would be a straightforward multi-site setup and does not require mod_rewrite, just a bunch of [`<virtualHost>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html) directives that point to each site.

If you need exactly the setup you describe (http://www.hostname.com/www.2ndhostname.com/directoryname) you would need one `<VirtualHost>` with all the domains as aliases, and a mod_rewrite based redirect to point incoming requests to the right directory.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The problem is that this needs to be automatically scalable - meaning that my PHP code needs to be able to create/destroy domain records on-the-fly (sorry, I didn't make that clear).

What I might do is have two domains: myapp.com + myapp2.com

Then can each domain#.com DNS record be setup to invisibly redirect to domain#.com.myapp2.com?  The server with myapp2.com would be setup for wildcard subdomains and would then use Mod_Rewrite to go to myapp.com/domain.com/

Sound at all plausible?

I'm new to DNS setup and trying to learn...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are aiming to do, but it sounds too complicated to my ears. How many servers do you exactly have, and how many do you *need*? Wouln't it be enough to map all domains to one server, and let mod_rewrite sort out the rest?

Comment: I agree, it seems too complicated.  I'm using Rackspace CloudSites to host the central app (it's cheap and allows for on-demand scaling), which unfortunately does not allow for any advanced configuration.  I am using Rackspace CloudServers (near-instant deployment, very inexpensive, scalable, root access) to handle the more advanced customization.  I've setup a similar config before (wildcard subdomains on a CloudServer redirected to a site on CloudSites) but the DNS issues now add another layer of complexity.

Comment: For what you need, the DNS thing isn't really that hard basically. You map a domain to a server. Period. The rest is up to Apache and PHP to handle. You can set up a Apache virtualHost that takes all incoming requests and forwards them to myapp.com/mydomain.com/params no problem. This can also be set up scalable, so that you don't have to set it up for every new domain. Whether programming a solution to add DNS entries is a sensible thing I don't know - it takes manual work to register the domain anyway, and typing in the right IP address should be just one more step in the process.