# How to mask URL address?

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

Think I have `domain.com` that redirects into `some.otherdomain.com`. 
I don't want to show exact url `some.otherdomain.com` to my sites visitors. 
I need to mask my URL, so that it will look like `domain.com`
Any possible way? .htaccess / javascript?

Comment: Maybe setup a load balancer like mod_proxy?

Comment: huh? That's not "redirecting"!

Comment: you cannot 'mask' it if its another server, otherwise spammers would be trying to trick people right and left with this fashion, showing them 'amazon' while they are on 'takeyourmulah.ru'

Comment: OP doesn't want to redirect.  They want to take the content from `domain.com` and have the web server on `some.otherdomain.com` write it out instead.  That's a proxy.

Comment: @Jakub - If you type in `amazon.com` in your web browser, Amazon is *redirecting* the content from one of its many thousands of servers.  You'll never know which one.  This is no different.

Comment: @MikeChristensen It doesn't have to be a proxy if both domains map to the same server. In that case it's a rewrite rather than a redirect.

Comment: I have no access to domain registrar. I only know that domain.com redirects into second domain

Comment: @Leven - True that.  I was kinda assuming they were different servers..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to hide your domain is to use a reverse proxy (apache, nginx, ...) and provide rewrite rules to it.

Comment: example please. Understood nothing

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `domain.com` and `some.otherdomain.com` are on two physically different servers, and you can't change the DNS information for any of them, you'll need to install a reverse proxy on `domain.com`.  You can use `mod_proxy` for this.  The docs are at:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

The following information is what you need to pay attention to:

> A reverse proxy, by contrast, appears to the client just like an
>   ordinary web server. No special configuration on the client is
>   necessary. The client makes ordinary requests for content in the
>   name-space of the reverse proxy. The reverse proxy then decides where
>   to send those requests, and returns the content as if it was itself
>   the origin.

There's an example of a reserve proxy in the docs, but you'll want something like this:

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://some.otherdomain.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://some.otherdomain.com/
```

Basically, any request that domains in will be proxied over to `some.otherdomain.com` - The local web server will forward the request over, buffer the data from `otherdomain.com`, then write the same data back out as if it were local data.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I have [ NO ] access to domain registrar. I only know that domain.com redirects into second domain, which I have access

Answer (score 1):

I always think the best way is doing such things via mod_rewrite (or similar) in the server configuration (Apache or whatever is used)

Answer (score 1):

On the Apache webserver of domain.com you have to enable:

1. mod_proxy
2. mod_rewrite
3. .htaccess

Once these requirements are completed then put this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT of `domain.com`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://some.otherdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

Important flag here is `P` (Proxy) which will basically make `domain.com` proxy all the requests to `some.otherdomain.com` without showing it in the browser. See here for more documentation on this flag: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: I have [ NO ] access to first domain or its server. I only know that domain.com redirects into second domain not via web server but via registrar's redirection

Comment: You started your question as `Think I have domain.com` which gives an impression that you manage first domain. However honestly now I don't even understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @epic_syntax - If you *don't* own `domain.com`, then you have no control over what it outputs period.  What you're asking to do is not possible.

Comment: how it could be possible if the domain.com is registered through private registrar (e.g. GoDaddy.com) . We do not have access tomodify their apache conf. to enable mod_proxy mod_rewrite .

Answer (score 0):

The easier way would be to set up a page on domain.com with an iframe on it and set the source of the iframe to some.otherdomain.com.  However, a user will be able to view source of the page and see that your iframe is pointing to some.otherdomain.com.

```
<iframe src="http://some.otherdomain.com/">...
```

The other option is to use a mod_rewrite in your .htaccess as shown in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962605/url-masking-with-dns-and-or-mod-rewrite).

Comment: Using an iframe would make deeplinking to your site much more difficult.

Comment: Yea, you'd have to dynamically append the rest of the URL path onto the end of the iframe URL.  Easy enough with PHP or even Javascript, but this is a pretty hacky solution and also wouldn't truly *mask* where the data is coming from.