# How to mask a URL via HTML or .htaccess

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, url

I am setting up a website that I want no one to know the URL for. For example, I send them a link that actually goes to the page, but the URL in the bar at the top has a completely different URL that I don't own. I'm not sure if this can be done in PHP, HTML, or the .htaccess file.

Comment: @SeanBright, sure it can: [Domain Masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Masking). That's not to say it isn't easy to detect depending on the method used, but it is possible to do what was asked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL Masking with DNS and/or Mod\_Rewrite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962605/url-masking-with-dns-and-or-mod-rewrite)

Comment: No @Andy , that post is about if you own all those domains, I want it so it shows up as a domain I don't own.

Comment: iframe? dns domainmasking ?

Comment: @PanamaJack iframe would need you to own the other domain, and dns the same.

Comment: @danwatco, Just realized the direction you meant. Doesn't quite make sense why you would want that but good luck.

Comment: So you want to display *your* document when someone visits, for example, `http://wikipedia.org/`?

Comment: Not when they visit it, just when I send them a disguised link such as bit.ly @unor

Comment: @danwatco: And when they click at this link, the browser’s address bar should still show the "wrong" (ex: `http://wikipedia.org/`) URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not possible**, unless

- you control the systems of the visitors (then you could, for example, change their DNS servers), or
- you find and exploit a bug in the browser/system.

You can make a link anchor text *look* like it leads to a specific domain not under your control, but the real URL will be used in any case. Example: [http://wikipedia.org/](http://example.com/).